# Update element in a set of pointer of elements before deletion

Tags: c++, set, multiset

I have some instances of a class allocated in an unordered_map. I also have different containers that store pointers to these elements with different orderings. Which means that for example, I have a std::set of pointers to the elements allocated in the map, ordered by a subset of the instances' fields.

Since I have access to the real elements, I can change their fields, but I know that I shouldn't do that on the fields that are used in the ordering of the set. In fact, what I need to do before changing those fields is to delete the object's pointer from the set, change those fields and insert it back again, like this:

```
set<Element*, Comparator> s; // Elements ordered by field_2

s.erase(element);
element->field_2 = 4;
s.insert(element);
```

However, the other containers that maintain different orderings are implemented by myself, and I know that I can change those values and then notify the container that the fields have been updated. So I'm wondering if I can change the order of those instructions to this one:

```
element->field_2 = 4;
s.erase(element);
s.insert(element);
```

The reason I want to do it this way is that I want all those containers to share the same interface. So ideally I would like to change the fields and then call the container's method container.value_updated(element).

So, can I modify the critical field_2 and then immediately call delete & insert? Or the deletion will fail since the value of field_2 can be inconsistent? (I think this will be implementation dependent but I want to make sure)

Comment: If `field_2` is used for order of `std::set` then the `std::set` is broken if you change the `field_2` of an instance which is element. The `std::set::erase()` may stop to work properly for the 2nd sample.

Comment: Is delete followed by insert the best way to sort items?

Comment: C++17 has defined https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/extract Maybe it can help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data which is used as key in a `std::set` may not be changed. Otherwise, the order of `std::set` is broken and addressing elements in the `std::set` cannot work anymore.

Out of curiosity, I tried to do it the wrong way.

Although I know it is undefined behavior, I got this running – a nice demonstration that bad things happen:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <vector>

typedef int Entry;

struct Less {
  bool operator()(const Entry *p1, const Entry *p2) const
  {
    return *p1 < *p2;
  }
};

int main()
{
  const int N = 10;
  std::vector<int> data;
  for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) data.push_back(i);
  std::set<Entry*, Less> set;
  for (int &value : data) set.insert(&value);
  // do it wrong
  data[2] = 12;
  set.erase(&data[2]);
  set.insert(&data[2]);
  // check result
  for (const Entry *pValue : set) std::cout << ' ' << *pValue;
  std::cout << '\n';
  // done
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
 0 1 12 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 12
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/757de42e6423d3d3)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

> So, can I modify the critical `field_2` and then immediately call delete & insert?

No. That has the potential to destroy the ordering of the pointers in the set.

> Or the deletion will fail since the value of `field_2` can be inconsistent?

That's a distinct possibility. However, at that point, you are looking at undefined behavior. It's impossible to predict what will happen.

> (I think this will be implementation dependent but I want to make sure)

The undefined behavior part is not implementation dependent.